# Food Selection Query

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table food which has the following constraints

```
Food

Name(which has the dish name)
category (cuisine name)
DeskNo(The table that it is placed on)


Food:
Name         Category     Deskno
pasta        Mexican         1
noodles      Chines          1
friedrice    Chinese         2
Tamarindrice Indian          2
```

And I have a Through table with

```
ThroughAway

category1
category2

ThrowAway
Category1      Category2
Indian         Chinese
Mexican        Indian
```

If category1 and category2 come together on same DeskNo those dishes will be thrown away.
I need to output the name of the dish that is in same DeskNo and there is danger that both might fall into the ThrownAway. Need some help

Comment: Can you provide several rows of sample data, and desired output of the query?

Comment: If the dish combination of Indian Chinese come on same table then throw the dish away. I need some help in writing query for this approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT Distinct a.Name AS Dish1, b.Name As Dish2
FROM Food a, Food b, ThroughAway c
WHERE a.Name <> b.Name AND a.Deskno = b.deskno AND 
(a.category = c.category1 AND c.category2 = b.category) ;
```

A self join to compare the dishes of same desk with the throw away table

Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0893e6/7

Comment: I made a mistake by selecting only one name in my query I was getting partial output. Now its working fine thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
select f1.name, f2.name from ThrowAway t
inner join Food f1 on f1.Category = t.Category1
inner join Food f2 on f2.Category = t.Category2
where f1.deskno = f2.deskno
```

But you should not join on varchar or smth like that, it's a realy bad practice.
Add ids, indexes and join on them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FOOD.DESKNO
FROM   FOOD INNER JOIN
THROW ON FOOD.CATEGORY = THROW.CAT1 INNER JOIN
THROW AS THROW_1 ON FOOD.CATEGORY = THROW_1.CAT2
```

Comment: if you need the desk number where a throw might occur try above.

Answer (score 0):

Food

Name(which has the dish name)
category (cuisine name)
DeskNo(The table that it is placed on)

Food:
Name         Category     Deskno
pasta        Mexican         1
noodles      Chines          1
friedrice    Chinese         2
Tamarindrice Indian          2